How is this compiler optimization legal?
I was reading the book Effective Java by Joshua Bloch. The author shows this code snippet in chapter on Concurrency:
public class StopThread {
  private static boolean stopRequested;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(() -> {
      int i = 0;
      while (!stopRequested) {
        i++;
      }
    });
    backgroundThread.start();
    
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    stopRequested = true;
  }
}

then goes on to say:

In the absence of synchronization, it is quote acceptable for the
virtual machine to transform the code:
while (!stopRequested)
  i++;

into this code:
if (!stopRequested)
  while (true)
    i++;


I am shocked at this. It changes the meaning of the code completely. The two are not equivalent so how can the VM make such an optimization (in fact its incorrect to even term this as optimization)? Can anyone explain it to me?

The two pieces of code are equivalent assuming no data races.

You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for

If you really want to go in depth, there's always the language spec. That is the fully authoritative source. It's not written in legalese, it's fairly readable.

It doesn't change the meaning of the code in a single-threaded context. Your thread never modifies stopRequested, so the loop is by definition infinite.

This short section of the Java Language Specification explains it well.

In the absence of synchronization, code that reads an object is allowed to, at its leisure, do either of the following:

Read the state of the object, and use the value read, optionally recoring it for future use as described in #2.

Identify some time when the object has been read, and after which neither any action to modify the state of the object, nor any synchronization action, has been performed, and use the value that had been read at that time.


Essentially, the code is transformed into:
boolean fastToReadBoolean = stopRequested;
while(!fastToReadBoolean)
  i++;

In many cases, compilers will turn while-at-the-top loops into a form that separates out the first conditional test from the rest:
boolean fastToReadBoolean = stopRequested;
if (!fastToReadBoolean)
   do
      i++;
   while(!fastToReadBoolean);

A compiler would be able to see that fastToReadBoolean was observed to be false before the loop was entered, and there's no way its value could change before the loop exists.  It would thus be allowed to treat the loop condition as constant for purposes of code generation (though not for purposes of determining static reachability).
Note that the semantics of Java are stronger than the semantics of C, in that data races in Java may cause the effects of the aforementioned "caching" to be visible, but the a read of an int, smaller integer type, or reference is required to yield a value that has been read from or written to the storage sometime.  In some situations such as String.hashCode(), reading a current value is preferable to reading a stale value, but isn't required for correctness.  In C, by contrast, data races may cause behavior that isn't consistent with any value that an object woul be physically capable of holding.

The answer is good, but, sort of jumps right into it without first thoroughly explaining the proper context here. Which is simply: Threads MAY cache values if you aren't using synchronization tools like synchronized - that's what the 'optimization' is trying to explain: ThatstopRequested might be cached.

@rzwitserloot: I think that's what my answer says, even though the second point's mention of synchronization might be redundant.  The point I wanted to make is that after the caching substitution is applied, none of the other transforms would have any additional impact on program behavior.


I am shocked at this. It changes the meaning of the code completely. The two are not equivalent so how can the VM make such an optimization ().

This is about a multi-threaded environment.  It's perfectly reasonable since the compiler has no idea that a different thread can check that stopRequested has been set to false.  So basically, it presumes that stopRequested will always be true and generates the optimized code.
The term is referred to as hoisting.  To prevent this, just declare stopRequested as volatile.

in fact its incorrect to even term this as optimization

Actually it is optimized.  In the first case, the variable would have to be tested each time to see if it was ever set to false.  In the optimized version, that simply represents a tight loop and no testing would need to be done.

"the compiler has no idea that a different thread can check that stopRequested has been set to false." if I can see by looking at the code that a different thread can change the value of stopRequested, why can't the compiler?

You can also see what certain values will be as they are executed.  The compiler does not follow that level of detail.  And the compiler has nothing to do with the other thread.  That is the JVM.  And it is the compiler that generates the code.  There are many instances where you have to help out the compiler to do things that you can see that the compiler can't.  Type witnessing for example.

Consider also if you have  a = 1L .  It would not compile yet you can "see" it needs to be a long.  L only applies to longs yet you have to declare a as a long because the compiler isn't designed to figure it out.  Same for a = "foo"; for strings.
